# Can we use JCo with SAP Cloud SDK for Java on localhost?

Tags: jco, sap-cloud-sdk

Can we use JCo with SAP Cloud SDK for Java on localhost?

I managed to use JCo on SAP Cloud Platform, but I'm not sure if it works on localhost.

https://blogs.sap.com/2020/05/08/how-to-call-function-modules-using-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java/

Without localhost testing, it takes so much time to develop Java Apps.

Regards,
Yohei

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge it does work with SCP Neo runtime.
It does not work for CF apps as JCo is contained in the SAP Java Buildpack which is not available locally.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
Can we write single code with JCo, which works on the both localhost and CF apps?

Comment: It is not about the code itself (syntax etc.), it is about the availability of JCo and the assumptions that JCo takes to be valid.

Comment: It helps when you tell us what you have tried already. Where exactly are you stuck with running your app on localhost? Your question does not really reveal all necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use JCo 3.x standalone in your local JVM environment for calling your SAP on-premise systems? This is what the standalone version is designed for. The client API is nearly the same, so it should work to write runtime environment independent JCo client application code.

You can get the JCo standalone SDK from https://support.sap.com/jco

Comment: Thank you for replying.

I just believe it is preferred to develop On-Premise RFC with single code line.  Anyway thank you.

Comment: OK, unfortunately I don't get what you want. What I wanted to say is just that your same JCo client source code will work with using the JCo 3.x standalone version on your localhost in your intranet directly to your on-premise ABAP system, and with using the JCo cloud version from the cloud platform via the Cloud Connector to your on-premise ABAP system. Only configs need to be adapted, but no code change.

Comment: What I'd like to say is that I just want to test my app on my local PC.  "My app" uses SAP cloud sdk and call RFM on-premise.
If I write codes with SAP Cloud SDK when calling RFM, it only works on CF.  It is inefficient to test on CF with every code changes.

Comment: Would be great if you could shed some light which particular problem you face when running your app on your local PC.